# Strongly convexity of a loss function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

I want to calculate the strongly convex parameter $\sigma$ for this loss function:
$$
l_Z(Z)=||Z-A||^2_F+\lambda tr[Z^TBZ]
$$
where $Z\in \mathcal{R}^{n\times m}$, the value of $A,B$ and $\lambda$ are known.

I have tried the Hessian approach, but fail to continue after the gradient:
$$
\nabla_Z l=2(\lambda B+I)Z-2A
$$

Any help on calculating the Hessian or other approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have computed the gradient already, notice that

$$
\nabla \ell(Z) - \nabla \ell(Z') = 2(\lambda B + I)(Z - Z')
$$

Suppose that $\lambda B + I \succeq \sigma I$ for some $\sigma > 0$. Then from the above it is immediate that

$$
\langle \nabla \ell(Z) - \nabla \ell(Z'), Z - Z' \rangle \geq 2\sigma \|Z - Z'\|_F^2
$$

The $2\sigma$ factor above is the modulus of strong convexity.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe we can let $\sigma$ be the smallest singular value of $\lambda B+I$?

Comment: Yes, this is the tightest lower bound you'll get.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)